# compare two files and print line if file name matches - large files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Want to search `file2.txt` with filenames in `file1.txt` with keywords like "`111.json`";
if there is a match in `file2.txt` then print that line to `file3.txt`.

**File1.txt**

```
2020-11-06 20:02:20 +0000 dirpath/one/111.json
2020-11-02 17:49:51 +0000 dirpath/one/112.json
2020-11-10 00:10:08 +0000 dirpath/one/two/211.json
```

**File2.txt**

```
etst   dir/one/111.json
etst   dir/one/112.json
etst   dir/one/113.json
etst   dir/one/114.json
etst   dir/one/two/211.json
etst   dir/two/212.json
etst   dir/two/213.json
etst   dir/two/214.json
```

---

**File3.txt**

```
etst   dir/one/111.json
etst   dir/one/112.json
etst   dir/one/two/211.json
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `comm` is your friend; see [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036). It'll be especially straightforward (and efficient, requiring only a single processing pass and a constant amount of memory) if the files are both sorted by the column you want to join on already.

Comment: How do you decide which parts of the names in column 4 of `file1.txt` should be used?  Is it really just the last component (`111.json`, etc)?  Otherwise, when do you use `one/111.json` vs `111.json` and how do you decide how much of column 2 in `file2.txt` should be matched.  Also, is the `etst` in `file2.txt` always that value, or does it change between lines?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy — really?  That looks for complete lines that do or don't match, but the matches here seem to be on parts of columns.  I initially thought that maybe `join` (and `sort` and Bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)) would help, but on seeing `dir/` vs `dirpath/`, I don't think it does, or not so easily.  There's a good deal of missing information in the specification of the problem, sadly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, right, so we extract the columns and use `comm` to find the intersection, then pull the rest of the lines out of the original file; one pass on each file done by comm, one pass done retrieving the remainder of the lines. Assuming, of course, that `etst` isn't constant; if it were, no need to refer to the original file at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ...fair point about `dirpath` vs `dir` (unless the distinction is an error on the OP's part and doesn't even exist in the first place); but that's still just a constant-time transform that can happen in the single pass between when the file is read and when it reaches `comm`.

Comment: ...anyhow, there are a lot of little details, but I don't see anything that's _difficult_ to address here in a manner that's both I/O and memory-efficient; and how to address each of those details should really be its own separate question, since they're all individually well-defined and each have simple answers (and we don't know how many of them are "real" problems at all, vs how many are just the question being posed in an unclear or ambiguous manner).

Comment: Yes, there's nothing insuperable to the OP who knows (one hopes) what is required.  It's just not obvious to those of us trying to help what the answers to the details are, because the lack of those details in the question prevent us from helping with a proper answer.  It might be that `grep -F -f modified.file1.txt file2.txt` would be sufficient, where the `modified.file1.txt` contains the patterns to be searched for, generated from the data in `file1.txt` by an appropriate transform, which is probably not very complex.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler updated my question, may if we just search with the filename like "111.json" 
I thought of cut out the first directory in file1 "dirpath" as it is only changes and search with rest of string in the file2 for absolute value

........in file2 "etst" will be same, I hope if there is a match we can append the output to file3, isn't it.,..

Infact I am trying to loop these and append to an excel file and end tag after loop closes

Comment: `grep -F -f <(sed 's%.*/%%' file1.txt) file2.txt` — see process substitution, etc, as referenced before.  The `sed` command removes everything up to the last slash — the `.*` is greedy.  I'm assuming Bash 4 or later — beware macOS.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...that approach isn't exactly memory-efficient, though; requires file1 to be fully read into memory, so there's a limit to the length it can handle.

Comment: that's working as expected. Thanks a lot @JonathanLeffler.....how do I add another constraint to include files with extension **.JSON** only